# If $rS_n=S_n+(ar^{n+1}-a)$ , how $S_n={ar^{n+1}-a\over r-1 }$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

In the book Discrete mathematics and its application I've seen a para

> We can see that from $$rS_n=S_n+(ar^{n+1}-a).$$ Solving for $S_n$ shows that if $r\neq1$, then $$S_n={(ar^{n+1}-a )\over r-1}$$

I've understood coming of the second equation from the first intuitively,but i am interested to see that How can i come with the second equation from the first by the laws of the equation in algebra.

(I am new to discrete math if this question makes no sense please notify me i will delete it)

Comment: Just squint :-) $rX = X + \square \overset{-X}{\implies} rX - X = X(r -1) = \square \overset{\div r - 1}{\implies} X = \frac{\square}{r - 1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is next to
$$rS_n=S_n+(ar^{n+1}-a)?$$ Well, we get (by adding to both sides by $-S_n$. or simply say that transpose $S_n$ to the left side)

$$rS_n-S_n=(ar^{n+1}-a)$$ and so (applying factoring at the left-hand side) we get
$$S_n(r-1)=(ar^{n+1}-a)$$ then dividing both sides by $r-1$ (if $r\neq 1$), we are done.